# Matching georeferenced data with shape file in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have a georeferenced event data set, in a data frame of the form:

```
LONGITUDE LATITUDE VAR1
33.4      4.4      5
33.4      4.4      3
33.4      4.4      1
30.4      4.2      2
28.4      5.1      2
```

It counts fatalities in events which are georeferenced. Apart from it, I have a shape file of the provinces in a country, like this:

```
> str(shapefile)
'data.frame':   216 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ CONSTI_COD: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Area      : num  20 11.7 10.7 223.3 38.7 ...
 $ PROVINCE_NAME  : Factor w/ 216 levels "CENTRAL","COAST",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num  0.193 0.152 0.201 0.872 0.441 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num  0.001628 0.000947 0.000867 0.018135 0.003145 ...

 ..@ polygons   :List of 216
   .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
   .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
   .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 36.9 -1.3
   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 0.00163
   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:151, 1:2] 36.8 36.8 36.8 36.9 36.9 ...
   .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
   .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 36.9 -1.3
   .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "0"
   .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 0.00163
 [...etc]
```

What I need to do is to place the event data within the provinces, i.e. add a fourth column to the first data frame which states in which province happened each event, based on the coordinates. So I would have something like this:

```
LONGITUDE LATITUDE VAR1 PROVINCE
33.4      4.4      5    CENTRAL
33.4      4.4      3    CENTRAL
33.4      4.4      1    CENTRAL
30.4      4.2      2    COAST
28.4      5.1      2    COAST
```

Is this posible? I think I found some time ago a post that explained how to do this (outside Stack Overflow), but I cannot find it now.

Thanks!

(Sorry if there is a similar question over here. I made a search, but I didn't find an answer, maybe because I don't really know what I'm looking for. I would really appreciate a link to a similar post.)

Comment: Knowing the terminology makes all the difference when searching - I remember it being very frustrating not knowing the important keywords!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're talking about is a "spatial join" (or "spatial intersection" or "overlay"). This is pretty straightforward with the help of the `over` function from the `sp` package.

Here's an example.

First, let's download and import a polygon shapefile of the world's countries.

```
download.file(paste0('http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//',
                     'www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/',
                     'ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip'), 
              f <- tempfile())
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
library(rgdal)
countries <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'ne_110m_admin_0_countries')
```

Now we'll create some random coordinate data that fall within the extent of the polygon shapefile. We then define the columns `x` and `y` as `coordinates`, and assign the same CRS as that of the polygons (although this may not be the case for your data; be sure to assign correct coordinate systems).

```
pts <- data.frame(x=runif(10, -180, 180), y=runif(10, -90, 90),
                  VAR1=LETTERS[1:10])
coordinates(pts) <- ~x+y  # pts needs to be a data.frame for this to work
proj4string(pts) <- proj4string(countries)

plot(countries)
points(pts, pch=20, col='red')
```

[image: shp]

Now we can perform the spatial overlay:

```
over(pts, countries)$admin

#  [1] <NA>      <NA>      Turkey    <NA>     
#  [5] Macedonia <NA>      China     Argentina
#  [9] <NA>      Canada   
# 177 Levels: Afghanistan Albania ... Zimbabwe
```

Note that in this case, some of the random points fell in the ocean (i.e. outside polygons). When intersected with the polygon object, these points return NA.

Now we `cbind` the desired attribute to `pts`:

```
cbind.data.frame(pts, country=over(pts, countries)$admin)

#             x          y VAR1   country
# 1   -52.59404 -37.422879    A      <NA>
# 2   -33.88867 -40.194482    B      <NA>
# 3    38.84383  37.272460    C    Turkey
# 4   -84.04949   7.118878    D      <NA>
# 5    20.98272  40.920470    E Macedonia
# 6  -155.32951 -37.612497    F      <NA>
# 7    99.40166  38.630049    G     China
# 8   -61.84025 -27.412885    H Argentina
# 9   -37.65287  -3.666080    I      <NA>
# 10 -112.81197  59.959475    J    Canada
```